# sikuli-ide not working/responding correctly

Tags: selenium, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

When I doublick click on Sikuli-ide.jar, then a dialogue appears, when I dont enter any option and click ok button then the application just closes and nothing happens.
why is it so, I want to start automation using selenium-ide.jar

can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your `JAVA_HOME`, Sikuli install and IDE has some problems with `Java 8`.

Comment: my java path was  not set .... after setting up the system variables, i have been able to run sikuli using command prompt.